# How to use regular expressions to pull something from a terminal output?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, terminal

I'm attempting to use the re module to look through some terminal output. When I ping a server through terminal using `ping -n 1 host` (I'm using Windows), it gives me much more information than I want. I want just the amount of time that it takes to get a reply from the server, which in this case is always denoted by an integer and then the letters 'ms'. The error I get explains that the output from the terminal is not a string, so I cannot use regular expressions on it.

```
from os import system as system_call        
import re       

def ping(host):
    return system_call("ping -n 1 " + host) == 0

host = input("Select a host to ping: ")

regex = re.compile(r"\w\wms")
final_ping = regex.search(ping(host))
print(final_ping)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` returns `0`, not anything too useful.  However, if we were to do `subprocess`, we can get teh output, and store it to a variable, `out`, then we can regex search that.

```
import subprocess      
import re       

def ping(host):
   ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   out, error = ping.communicate()
   return str(out)


host = input("Select a host to ping: ")

final_ping = re.findall("\d+ms",ping(host))[0]
print(final_ping)
```

Output:

```
22ms
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the `\d+` does?

Comment: It means "any digit" (1234567890).

Comment: and the [0] at the end of the statement?

Comment: It accesses the first instance of the search.  It returns all 4 instances of the same value, you could change the regex or use [0].

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Your `ping` function doesn't return the terminal output. It only returns a `bool` that reports if the ping succeeded. The ping output is directly forwarded to the terminal that runs the Python script.
2. Python 3 differentiates between strings (for text, consisting of Unicode codepoints) and bytes (for any data, consisting of bytes). As Python cannot know that `ping` only outputs ASCII text, you will get a `bytes` object if you don't specify which text encoding is in use.

It would be the best to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.system`. This is also suggested by the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=system#os.system).

One possible way is to use `subprocess.check_output` with the `encoding` parameter to get a string instead of bytes:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

def ping(host):
    return check_output(
       "ping -n 1 " + host,
       shell=True,
       encoding=sys.getdefaultencoding()
     )

...
```

EDIT: The `encoding` parameter is only supported since Python 3.6. If you are using an older version, try this:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

def ping(host):
    return check_output(
       "ping -n 1 " + host,
       shell=True
     ).decode()

...
```